# Format date in Datatable output

Tags: r, sorting, shiny, dt

```
library(DT)
seq_dates <- data.frame(dates = as.Date("2017-01-01") + 1:6 * 100)
datatable(seq_dates) %>% formatDate(1, "toDateString")
```

I get a datatable in viewer pane displaying dates in following format "Mon May 22 2017".

Q - How can I format date column as "MM-YY"

If I do,

```
dplyr::mutate(seq_dates, dates = format(dates, format = "%b-%Y")) %>%
  datatable()
```

I get the required date format, but in this second case column sorting doesn't work (sorting is done on alphabets rather than dates.)

P.S - I'm implementing this on shiny.

Answer (score 14):

Hi in these cases do I think the best solution is to add a dummy column with the dates in orginal format and have the dates column being sorted according to the values in the DUMMY column. This is in **Datatable** quite easily done. Example code below.

```
seq_dates <- data.frame(dates = as.Date("2017-01-01") + 1:6 * 100)
datatable(seq_dates %>% mutate(DUMMY = dates,dates = format(dates, format = "%b-%Y")),
          options = list(
            columnDefs = list(
              list(targets = 1,orderData = 2),
              list(targets = 2, visible = FALSE)
             )
           ))
```

Comment: Nice workaround. I was hoping for a solution with `formatDate()`. If there is no more direct solution in a few days, I will validate yours.

Comment: Since I (OP) needed the MM-YY format, I converted the date col as a factor with proper levels - that did the trick!

Comment: @Vasim cool that you found your own solution, but as my solution allowed for every kind of date format, so I don't see any need for you to down vote the answer.

Comment: @Vasim I mean to get what you want just change to `format = "%m-%y"`

Comment: By today, the column-enumeration starts with 0.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth (and using `formatDate`), the best that I can do is as follows:

```
datatable(seq_dates) %>% 
  formatDate(
    columns = 1, 
    method =  "toLocaleDateString", 
    params = list(
      'en-US', 
      list(
        year = 'numeric', 
        month = 'numeric')
      )
    )
```

And this yields date values like `4/2017` and `10/2017`.

I've tried to find these parameter options (in github and the original datatables documentation) but to no avail. The only example in DT uses the parameters of `short`, `long` and `numeric`.

Comment: The `params` refer to the parameters the JavaScript method takes, in this case the parameters for  `toLocaleDateString`. The parameters for `toLocalDateString` can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), and in the docs for [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat).

Answer (score 0):

Converting `"%b-%y"` "dates" to date format is not an easy thing as I could see...

If you're not too attached to displaying `"%b-%y"` format, the easy way is to use `"%Y-%m"` or `"%y-%m"` format and the filter will work just fine :

```
library(DT)

seq_dates <- as.data.frame(seq(Sys.Date() - 100, Sys.Date(), by = "m"))
seq_dates <- format(seq_dates, format = "%y-%m")

datatable(seq_dates)

#resulting in

#1        2017-02
#2        2017-03
#3        2017-04
#4        2017-05

#or

#1        17-02
#2        17-03
#3        17-04
#4        17-05
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a render method that you can use:

```
datatable( ...
  options = list(..
     columnDefs = list(..
        list(targets = c(1), render = JS(
                             "function(data, type, row, meta) {",                              
                              "return type === 'display' ? new Date(data).toLocaleString() : data;"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using lubridate's yearmon and converting the column to character.

```
library(DT)
library(lubridate)

seq_dates <- data.frame(dates = as.Date("2017-01-01") + 1:6 * 100)
seq_dates$YEARMON <- as.character(as.yearmon(seq_dates$dates))
datatable(seq_dates)
```